# Libgdx Sprite's position relative to the SpriteBatch's position

Tags: android, libgdx

I wonder know how to do for set a sprite that is following the spritebatch's Vector position :

```
Vector3 position;
Matrix4 camera;
SpriteBatch batch;

...
//Some code
...

position.set(-1, 0, 0);
camera.setTranslation(position);

batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera);
```

so I got a sprite and I want that the sprite alway stay at the same position **Relative** to the SpriteBatch's position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spriteBatch does not have a position. Do you mean relative to camera's position?

use something like: camera.position.x+(your relative position e.g. +100, or -80) and the same for y.